# NskAlgoSdk.jar crashes in SDK 33 Android app

Tags: jar, sdk, crash

The application for the NeuroSky MindWave neuroheadset, which worked fine under SDK 30, crashes while accessing NeuroSky's NskAlgoSdk.jar file when I'm trying to change the code for SDK 33. NeuroSky stopped library support in 2016.

Even if to create a simple new SDK 33 project in Android Studio and add a few lines to it to work with the Neurosky's NskAlgoSdk.jar library (2016), it instantly crashes on the phone when accessing the very first library class NskAlgoSdk. What can be a problem?

```
package com.android.app;

        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;

        import com.neurosky.AlgoSdk.NskAlgoSdk;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NskAlgoSdk nskAlgoSdk;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nskAlgoSdk = new NskAlgoSdk(); //crashes here

    }
}
```

This is the code of decompiled NskAlgoSdk.class:

```
// 
// Decompiled by Procyon v0.5.36
// 

package com.neurosky.AlgoSdk;

import android.util.Log;

public class NskAlgoSdk
{
    private static final String TAG = "NskAlgoSdkTag Wrapper";
    private static NskAlgoSdk.OnBPAlgoIndexListener mOnBPAlgoIndexListener;
    private static NskAlgoSdk.OnEyeBlinkDetectionListener mOnEyeBlinkDetectionListener;
    private static NskAlgoSdk.OnAttAlgoIndexListener mOnAttAlgoIndexListener;
    private static NskAlgoSdk.OnMedAlgoIndexListener mOnMedAlgoIndexListener;
    private static NskAlgoSdk.OnStateChangeListener mOnStateChangeListener;
    private static NskAlgoSdk.OnSignalQualityListener mOnSignalQualityListener;
    
    public static native int NskAlgoInit(final int p0, final String p1);
    
    public static native int NskAlgoUninit();
    
    public static native int NskAlgoStart(final boolean p0);
    
    public static native int NskAlgoPause();
    
    public static native int NskAlgoStop();
    
    public static native int NskAlgoSetConfig(final int p0, final NskAlgoConfig p1);
    
    public static native int NskAlgoDataStream(final int p0, final short[] p1, final int p2);
    
    public static native String NskAlgoSdkVersion();
    
    public static native String NskAlgoAlgoVersion(final int p0);
    
    public void setOnBPAlgoIndexListener(final NskAlgoSdk.OnBPAlgoIndexListener listener) {
        NskAlgoSdk.mOnBPAlgoIndexListener = listener;
    }
    
    public static void NskAlgoBPAlgoIndexListener(final float delta, final float theta, final float alpha, final float beta, final float gamma) {
        if (NskAlgoSdk.mOnBPAlgoIndexListener != null) {
            NskAlgoSdk.mOnBPAlgoIndexListener.onBPAlgoIndex(delta, theta, alpha, beta, gamma);
        }
    }
    
    public void setOnEyeBlinkDetectionListener(final NskAlgoSdk.OnEyeBlinkDetectionListener listener) {
        NskAlgoSdk.mOnEyeBlinkDetectionListener = listener;
    }
    
    public static void NskAlgoEyeBlinkDetectionListener(final int strength) {
        if (NskAlgoSdk.mOnEyeBlinkDetectionListener != null) {
            NskAlgoSdk.mOnEyeBlinkDetectionListener.onEyeBlinkDetect(strength);
        }
    }
    
    public void setOnAttAlgoIndexListener(final NskAlgoSdk.OnAttAlgoIndexListener listener) {
        NskAlgoSdk.mOnAttAlgoIndexListener = listener;
    }
    
    public static void NskAlgoAttAlgoIndexListener(final int value) {
        if (NskAlgoSdk.mOnAttAlgoIndexListener != null) {
            NskAlgoSdk.mOnAttAlgoIndexListener.onAttAlgoIndex(value);
        }
    }
    
    public void setOnMedAlgoIndexListener(final NskAlgoSdk.OnMedAlgoIndexListener listener) {
        NskAlgoSdk.mOnMedAlgoIndexListener = listener;
    }
    
    public static void NskAlgoMedAlgoIndexListener(final int value) {
        if (NskAlgoSdk.mOnMedAlgoIndexListener != null) {
            NskAlgoSdk.mOnMedAlgoIndexListener.onMedAlgoIndex(value);
        }
    }
    
    public void setOnStateChangeListener(final NskAlgoSdk.OnStateChangeListener listener) {
        NskAlgoSdk.mOnStateChangeListener = listener;
    }
    
    public static void NskAlgoSdkStateChangeListener(final int state, final int reason) {
        if (NskAlgoSdk.mOnStateChangeListener != null) {
            NskAlgoSdk.mOnStateChangeListener.onStateChange(state, reason);
        }
    }
    
    public void setOnSignalQualityListener(final NskAlgoSdk.OnSignalQualityListener listener) {
        NskAlgoSdk.mOnSignalQualityListener = listener;
    }
    
    public static void NskAlgoSignalQualityListener(final int level) {
        if (NskAlgoSdk.mOnSignalQualityListener != null) {
            NskAlgoSdk.mOnSignalQualityListener.onSignalQuality(level);
        }
    }
    
    static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("NskAlgo");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("NskAlgoSdkTag Wrapper", "Load lib error: " + e.toString());
        }
        Log.i("NskAlgoSdkTag Wrapper", "Loaded NskAlgo library");
    }
}
```

I tried with different new project configurations (build.grade, etc.) and on different Android phones (Android 6.0, 12.0), added & removed 'android.enableJetifier=true' line in gradle.properties file, nothing helps. App crashes. NeuroSky stopped software support in 2016. How to make this NskAlgoSdk.jar library to work?